How to run sequential animations without one overlap the other framer motion
I'm working on a React project using Framer Motion and need to run multiple animations sequentially. Each animation should start only after the previous one finishes, ensuring no overlap.
For example:

First animation runs (e.g., a fade-in effect).
Once it completes, the second animation starts (e.g., a scale-up
effect).
Finally, the first animation begins after the second one ends.

I've tried using delay and transition settings, but I can't figure out how to chain them without manual timing adjustments. Is there a built-in way in Framer Motion to handle sequential animations cleanly? Or do I need a custom logic to manage their timing?
Any help or examples would be appreciated!

You can accomplish sequential animations in React with the useAnimation hook from Framer Motion.

useAnimate provides a way of using the animate function that is scoped to the elements within your component. This allows you to use manual animation controls, timelines, selectors scoped to your component, and automatic cleanup. It provides a scope ref, and an animate function where every DOM selector is scoped to this ref.

I'm not going to quote all of their docs, but I'll point out that the animate function has a Promise-like API, which means you can have animations wait for other animations to finish before running.
export function Example() {
  const [scope, animate] = useAnimate();

  useEffect(() => {
    const playAnimations = async () => {
      // Animate the div to the right 20px, then to the
      // left -20px, then back to the center.
      await animate(scope.current, { x: 20 });
      await animate(scope.current, { x: -20 });
      await animate(scope.current, { x: 0 });
    };

    playAnimations();
  });

  return <div ref={scope}></div>;
}

I created this little demo that shows it working.
Note: I thought about the possibility of having some sort of queue I could push animations to that would run sequentially, so I created that system with React Context. You'll see the code for that in the demo.  I understand it's quite a step up from the basic examples, but I'll do my best to leave some helpful comments in there.
